# Using const strings in curl_init/curl_setopt

Tags: php, curl

This may be trivial but I'm going crazy.
Why the following IS working:

```
class myClass {
  public function __construct() {
    $ch = curl_init("http://myserver.com/myscript.php");
    $fields = array('myKey' => 'myValue');
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($fields));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    echo curl_error($ch);
    echo $result
  }
}
$instance = new myClass();
```

...or...

```
class myClass {
  private $uri = "http://myserver.com/myscript.php"; // <<---
  public function __construct() {
    $ch = curl_init($uri); // <<--
    $fields = array('myKey' => 'myValue');
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($fields));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    echo curl_error($ch);
    echo $result
  }
}
$instance = new myClass();
```

... while this is NOT working:

```
class myClass {
  const URI = "http://myserver.com/myscript.php"; // <<---
  public function __construct() {
    $ch = curl_init(URI); // <<--
    $fields = array('myKey' => 'myValue');
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($fields));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    echo curl_error($ch);
    echo $result
  }
}
$instance = new myClass();
```

I get the the following curl error:

```
"Could not resolve remote host URI"
```

Looks like the const strings don't get expanded in the function curl_init. The same happens if I use curl_setopt instead.
I've google around but, alas, with no result.
Any idea?

EDIT: I apologize for the typo. I've written the code thinking of the problem of the constant. That's why I didn't pay attention to the "public function". That was not my issue. I've corrected the code. No, as far as I know, there's no version of PHP where you can omit "public function" before __construct.

Comment: Hm, what do you get if you simply dump the constant inside your method?

Comment: And for the less advanced amongst us: which version of php is that where you apparently can omit the `function` keyword in your declaration of the method `__construct()`?

Comment: `URI` references a global constant, not the `myClass::URI` one.

Comment: @mario Indeed, well spotted. Actually this should throw a warning in the error log file... Also any decent IDE should point that out.

Comment: $this->uri or self::URI

Comment: @mario Ach... gotcha! Thanks, Mario. As always, the most trivial things are the last which fall under my eyes! If you turn your comment in an answer I'll accept and up-vote it. :-)